# convert text file to xml in java

Tags: java, xml

I have a text file with following entries

```
1 
244699000
52.467286666666666
4.611188333333334
```

I want to convert this to XML file as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SYSTEM-TRACKS> 
<AIS-SENSOR ID ="1">
    <MMSI>244699000 </MMSI>
    <LATITUDE> 52.467286666666666 </LATITUDE>
    <LONGITUDE> 4.611188333333334 </LONGITUDE>  
</AIS-SENSOR> 
</SYSTEM-TRACKS>
```

Here is the code which I found

```
public class ToXML {

BufferedReader in;
StreamResult out;

TransformerHandler th;
AttributesImpl atts;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new ToXML().doit();
}

public void doit() {
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data"));
        out = new StreamResult("data.xml");
        initXML();
        String str;

        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {

            process(str);

        }
        in.close();
        closeXML();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void initXML() throws ParserConfigurationException,
        TransformerConfigurationException, SAXException {
    // JAXP + SAX
    SAXTransformerFactory tf = (SAXTransformerFactory) SAXTransformerFactory
            .newInstance();

    th = tf.newTransformerHandler();
    Transformer serializer = th.getTransformer();
    serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
    // pretty XML output
    serializer.setOutputProperty(
            "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
    serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    th.setResult(out);
    th.startDocument();
    atts = new AttributesImpl();
    th.startElement("", "", "SYSTEM-TRACKS", atts);

}

public void process(String s) throws SAXException {
    String elements[] = s.split("\\r?\\n");
    atts.clear();

    th.startElement("", "", "AIS-SENSOR", atts);
    th.characters(elements[0].toCharArray(), 0, elements[0].length());

    th.startElement("", "", "MMSI", atts);
    th.characters(elements[1].toCharArray(), 0, elements[1].length());
    th.endElement("", "", "MMSI");

    th.startElement("", "", "LATITUDE", atts);
    th.characters(elements[2].toCharArray(), 0, elements[2].length());
    th.endElement("", "", "LATITUDE");

    th.startElement("", "", "LONGITUDE", atts);
    th.characters(elements[3].toCharArray(), 0, elements[3].length());
    th.endElement("", "", "LONGITUDE");

}

public void closeXML() throws SAXException {
    th.endElement("", "", "AIS-SENSOR");
    th.endElement("", "", "SYSTEM-TRACKS");
    th.endDocument();
}
```

}

But when i execute it i get following error

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at ToXML.process(ToXML.java:76)
at ToXML.doit(ToXML.java:38)
at ToXML.main(ToXML.java:26)
```

Can anybody help me with making a correct XML file as shown above ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html

Comment: Why don't you use a debugger to narrow down the problem yourself? (If you don't know how to do that, I very much recommend that you learn it, because it is certainly faster than asking a question here)

Comment: Look at line 76, how is it accessing an array position outside it's size?  (this is pretty basic, it wouldn't hurt for you to highlight line 76 because I'm certainly not going to load your code in an editor to figure it out myself)

Comment: I expect you are loading a blank line, so the split will not be the array you expect.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestion..

Comment: so what have you discovered as a result of these suggestions? Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Use the DOM :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder b = f.newDocumentBuilder();
DOMImplementation i = b.getDOMImplementation();
Document d = i.createDocument( null , null , null );
```

Then, just build it adding nodes :

```
d.appendChild( d.createElement( ... ) ... );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method is very strange. You are reading line by line, and then splitting the line by newline, but there is only one value per line, so your split will only return one entry. I suggest this approach:

```
    String str;
    int counter = -1;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        counter++;
        if(counter % 4 == 0) {
            process1(str); // add AIS-SENSOR element
            continue;
        }
        if(counter % 4 == 1) {
            process2(str); // add MMSI element
            continue;
        }
        if(counter % 4 == 2) {
            process3(str); // add LATITUDE element
            continue;
        }
        if(counter % 4 == 3) {
            process4(str); // add LONGITUDE element and close AIS-SENSOR
            continue;
        }          
    }
```

The `counter` keeps track of the current line in the file. Each of the `process1` will add a different element depending of the value on the corresponding line.

Comment: Neat and clean! Good idea

Answer (score 0):

You call process with just a single line from your file and then you try to split by new lines. Your array is probably of length 1.

```
String tmp = "";
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) 
{
    tmp += str;
}
process(tmp);
```

Try this instead.

Comment: This approach will only work if you have a single group of four values, because he has no loop in the `process` method.

Answer (score 0):

first in doit() you read a line from your file (which means untuil your first linebreak)
then you are gonna split the read line on linebreals.

so the split will always give an array with length 1 and this causes to give an exception when you use index 1(2nd element in the array).

Your txt file should contain all 4 lines on 1 line it seems, or you should rewrite your code to handle the txt file as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Read your text file into XML like this:

```
void readXML(){
    File textFile=...
    Scanner scanner= new Scanner(textFile);
    ContentHandler xmlContentHandler xml=...
   //make sure to startDocument() with xmlContentHandler 

    while (scanner.hasNext()){
        addStartNodeWithAttribute("AIS-SENSORD", scanner.next());

        //move these to a method and use a for loop i=0..<3
        xmlContentHandler.startElement("","","MMSI",new AttributesImpl());
        String mmsi=scanner.next();
        contenthandler.characters(mmsi.toCharArray(), 0, mmsi.length());
        contenthandler.endElement("","","MMSI");

        xmlContentHandler.startElement("","","LATITUDE",new AttributesImpl());
        String lat=scanner.next();
        contenthandler.characters(lat.toCharArray(), 0, lat.length());
        contenthandler.endElement("","","LATITUDE");

        xmlContentHandler.startElement("","","LONGITUDE",new AttributesImpl());
        String long=scanner.next();
        contenthandler.characters(long.toCharArray(), 0, long.length());
        contenthandler.endElement("","","LONGITUDE");
    }

    //make sure to endDocument() with xmlContentHandler
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// This is the original coding with the necessary changes to make it work.
// 1. Out destination is a FileWriter
// 2. Read the 4 lines into an array.
// 3. Process the array.
//      patrice_cotte@hotmail.com
package com.my.package;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXTransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.TransformerHandler;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.AttributesImpl;

/* 
 * This program reads a 4 lines text file land creates an XML structure around
 * the raw data. The XML structure is then copied to an xml output file. 
 */
public class Txt2XML {

    BufferedReader in;
    StreamResult out;

    TransformerHandler th;
    AttributesImpl atts;

    // Here's our entry point ... 
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Txt2XML().doit();
    }

    public void doit() {
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("conf/testdata.txt"));
            out = new StreamResult(new FileWriter("conf/testdata.xml"));
            initXML();
            String str;
            // declare an array that can contain 4 strings
            String[] SArray=new String[4];
            int i = 0;

            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
//              System.out.println("input line: " + str);
                SArray[i]=str;
                i++;

            }

            process(SArray);

            in.close();
            closeXML();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void initXML() throws ParserConfigurationException,
            TransformerConfigurationException, SAXException {
        // JAXP + SAX
        SAXTransformerFactory tf = (SAXTransformerFactory) SAXTransformerFactory
                .newInstance();

        th = tf.newTransformerHandler();
        Transformer serializer = th.getTransformer();
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
        // pretty XML output
        serializer.setOutputProperty(
                "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        th.setResult(out);
        th.startDocument();
        atts = new AttributesImpl();
        th.startElement("", "", "SYSTEM-TRACKS", atts);

    }

    public void process(String[] elements) throws SAXException {
//      System.out.println("number of elements: " + elements.length);
        atts.clear();

        th.startElement("", "", "AIS-SENSOR", atts);
        th.characters(elements[0].toCharArray(), 0, elements[0].length());

        th.startElement("", "", "MMSI", atts);
        th.characters(elements[1].toCharArray(), 0, elements[1].length());
        th.endElement("", "", "MMSI");

        th.startElement("", "", "LATITUDE", atts);
        th.characters(elements[2].toCharArray(), 0, elements[2].length());
        th.endElement("", "", "LATITUDE");

        th.startElement("", "", "LONGITUDE", atts);
        th.characters(elements[3].toCharArray(), 0, elements[3].length());
        th.endElement("", "", "LONGITUDE");

    }

    public void closeXML() throws SAXException {
        th.endElement("", "", "AIS-SENSOR");
        th.endElement("", "", "SYSTEM-TRACKS");
        th.endDocument();
    }
}
```